# How do I add parameter elements using a for loop?

Tags: python

using the cs1graphics module, I made a List containing 4 Point objects. I want to draw a Polygon using the Points in the List object by adding one element from the List to the Polygon parameter with each iteration (in a for loop). The Point objects in the list need to be STACKED on top of one another in Polygon in order to draw out the whole thing. What actually happens is the Point object from a position in the List will override the previous object from the previous iteration. In the end, I end up "drawing" a single Point (namely, the last Point in the List). How do I fix this?

edit: I tried using .append but that turns all the parameters into a List object and obviously I can't draw Lists.

```
self._list = [Point(200,200),Point(400,200),Point(400,400),Point(200,400),Point(200,200)]
    for i in range(4):
        self._poly = Polygon(self._list[i],)
```

Comment: what arguments does `Polygon` object accepts ?

Comment: try passing in the list itself without a loop like `self._poly = Polygon(self._list)`

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
self._list = [Point(200,200),Point(400,200),Point(400,400),Point(200,400),Point(200,200)]
self._poly = Polygon(self._list)
```

and

```
self._list = [Point(200,200),Point(400,200),Point(400,400),Point(200,400),Point(200,200)]
self._poly = Polygon(*self._list)
```

will work. No loops are needed.

If you insist on incrementally building a polygon in a loop, you can do this:

```
self._list = [Point(200,200),Point(400,200),Point(400,400),Point(200,400),Point(200,200)]
self._poly = Polygon()
for point in self._list:
    self._poly.addPoint(point)
```

Comment: First two are brilliant. Thanks. I had no idea you could plot out points contained in a list without extracting the points as separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass in the list itself, like this:

```
self._list = [Point(200,200),Point(400,200),Point(400,400),Point(200,400)]
self._poly = Polygon(self._list)
```

Note that you [don't need the last point](http://www.cs1graphics.org/doc/1.0/classcs1graphics_1_1Polygon.html#c775ee34451fdfa742b318538164070e):

> The last point is automatically connected back to the first to close the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
self._poly = Polygon(*self._list)
```

The `*` unpacks the list into arguments, and passes those as separate arguments to the function.

You could also just pass in the list of points itself.

```
self._poly = Polygon(self._list)
```

It will work just as well.

Comment: The docs say you can pass in a list *or* the points as separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Polygon with the first 4 points:

self._poly = Polygon(*self._list[:4])

In your code you are creating 4 Polygons each with a single Point.